# How to connect my Angular Website to the Network Solutions Domain?

Tags: angularjs, dns

I am trying to collect my Angular Website to the Network Solutions domain but I can only do the localhost:4200. I want to change that to the domain I bought from Network Solutions, how can I do that? Thanks for any responses.

Answer (score 0):

Hosting angular project doesn't differ a lot on hosting a javascript file inside a simple html/vanilla js project, of course you need first to get that bundle.js of your Angular project and to do so, build your project first with:

`ng build --prod`

Check the official docs [here](https://angular.io/guide/deployment) for more details.